# Cannot match request url with HttpTestingController

Tags: angular, api, unit-testing

I have just stareted writing unit test in Angular. At first, I would like to write test for my service to fetch data from external server. I tried to check type of method. I used some tutorial, but I cannot connect with server. Below is presented my code.

```
import { GitHubService} from './github.service';
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  HttpTestingController
} from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('GitHubService', () => {
  let service: GitHubService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [GitHubService]
    });

    service = TestBed.get(GitHubService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should create GitHubService', inject(
    [GitHubService],
    (service: GitHubService) => {
      expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }
  ));

  it('service url should be a GET method', () => {
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${service.API_URL}/users`);
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });
});
```

After running `ng test` the result is `1 FAILED, 1 SUCCESS` and filed error: `Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: https://api.github.com/users", found none.`. I have been looking for answer in net but solutions not working. What is wrong with my code and what I should correct? Thanks for advices.

Comment: You never call any method of your service anywhere (and subscribe to the Observable it returns), so it never sends any request, so the test fails because, indeed, the mock backend never receives anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to mark that if you use `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`, you should also provide it in test file